# How do I change my language to spanish on Pages 8?

Tags: pages

My computer is a PowerPC running Pages 08. I am now living in Spain and would like to know how to change the language.
 I would like to have Pages 08 in English, but I would like it to spell check in Spanish.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?  You just change it to spanish and Pages will be in Spanish.  Or are you talking about spellcheck?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Inspector > Text > More > Language